# How do you properly wash hands after dealing with raw chicken?

Tags: chicken, raw-meat, cleaning

Whenever I get done dealing with raw chicken, I feel like I need to wash my hands repeatedly with hot water and soap. Is this going to remove the potential bacteria away or is there a different way I should be cleaning my hands?

Comment: Your fine, as long as your washing your hands completely. Don't stress it. The fact that your being mindful of it means your probably not going to have problems.

Comment: I wash my hands with hot water and anti-bac soap, then a little alcohol hand rub after. It may be a little OCD, but I have had food poisoning from undercooked chicken and it's not pleasant at all: I lost 14 pounds in 3 days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I recall from all my food safety training: to properly wash your hands, wet them with warm water (at least 100 F), apply soap, scrub all over your hands and in between your fingers for 20 seconds and rinse.  That should thoroughly remove the bad bacteria and any other debris clinging to your hands.  That should be all you need.

Comment: I think it was 30 seconds last time I took serveSafe, anyhow. To add to this answer. Under your finger nails is a hot spot you don't have to go crazy digging them out just keep it in mind and make sure to check them. (there are nail brushes but I hate them)

Comment: Remember also that your hands were dirty when you turned on the tap. The proper procedure is to dry your hands with paper towel while the water is still running, then use the paper towel as a 'glove' when you turn off the tap. Discard immediately without changing which part of the paper towel you are touching.

Comment: 30 seconds, warm water, soap, and soft scrubbing is all that's needed.  It's not a toxic problem, just a simple clean that's needed.

Answer (score 3):

When I worked in a hospital, they taught us to get rid of germs or bacteria on your hands you had to use warm water and soap and keep washing until you have completed the song "Happy Birthday", then rinse well  starting with warm water tapering down to cold to close all pores.